# Why does my Mathematica figure not work with PSFrag?

Tags: graphics, psfrag, wolfram-mathematica

I created an image in *Mathematica* with some labels that, for some reason, refuse to be substituted when using PSFrag.

Specifically, the *Mathematica* code

```
image = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, PlotLabel-> "label"]
Export[NotebookDirectory<>"image.eps",image]
```

will create the image

[image]

The following PSFrag code should, in principle, substitute the label `label` with a nicely formatted `$\sin(x)$`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}

\begin{document}

  \psfrag{label}{$\sin(x)$}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image.eps}

\end{document}
```

Indeed, a very similar version will work on the `example.eps` image provided by the PSFrag package in its documentation. However, the label is not replaced by my `dvips` driver. What is going wrong?

Comment: this looks kind of interesting, but for truly beautiful graphics you might look at `pgfplots` or `PSTricks`

Comment: @cmhughes Those are nice, but they cannot do the heavy numerical integrations required by my thesis work. Every tool has its place.

Comment: but you can still export the heavy numerical integration results to a text file that you can then read with `pgfplots` or `pstricks`.

Comment: Following your example directly within Mathematica 8.0, I receive as output the entire label `(label)`.

Comment: @Werner I'm running Mathematica 9.0.1 over Ubuntu 12.04. I'm not sure at all what different versions or OSs will do.

Comment: I just found, belatedly, [this duplicate in StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384887/mathematica-8-0-and-psfrag). I guess that's what happens to newcomers who don't search parent sites, and to questions that don't get migrated out of them.

Answer (score 5):

This turns out to be the fault of *Mathematica*'s export protocol to EPS. If you inspect such a file directly in a text editor, the code corresponding to the label has been split up into single letters:

```
(l) N
P
p
3 10.5 m
(a) N
P
p
7.797 10.5 m
(b) N
P
p
13.203 10.5 m
(e) N
P
p
18 10.5 m
(l) N
```

That is, the string `(label)`, which is what PSFrag hunts for, has been split into the five different single-character strings `(l)`, `(a)`, `(b)`, `(e)` and `(l)`.

To fix this, simply change the quoted code above with the proper `(label)`, or change your labels to single characters.

Answer (score 3):

You may also like to try [MathPSFrag](http://wwwth.mpp.mpg.de/members/jgrosse/mathpsfrag/), which I've had lots of success with in the past.

It automatically creates (customisable) psfrag labels for *every* string in the image.